# Is there an issue with installing The Darkness II to the hard drive?

Tags: xbox-360, the-darkness-2

When trying to install the Xbox 360 version of *The Darkness II*, to the hard drive, the system does nothing and the game never gets installed.

The install appears to start, but the screen stays at the Installing screen at 0% progress indefinitely, all while showing the spinning wait symbol. I left it for 30 minutes and no change was made, and tried again multiple times. Attempting to then exit out back the Xbox Home fails, and cancelling the install also fails. The only option other than turning the system off that I could find, is to hit the Guide button and start the game itself, or starting another game. The game does play fine so far, and the disc doesn't appear to be scratched in any way.

I did update the game to the latest release when starting it directly from the disc, but that didn't change anything. Is there any fix for this hard drive intall problem, or is this a limited problem with an unknown resolution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually that means a problem with Xbox Live service. Again, usually, installing while signed out works.

Judging by the link Dean posted, that is the case with Darkness II.

Answer (score 0):

Just found the answer to our problem

http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/621308-/61907326

Comment: Would you mind posting the steps you took to solve your problem?  A link is nice, but having the answer here on the site is better in the long term :)